# Struggling with a countifs

Tags: excel

I have a table that is set as;

| Name | Date1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| persons name | AL | AL | AL | AL |

Where if it is AL or not determines if they are on annual leave

I'm trying to make a new table on a seperate sheet that will tell me how many times Person1 is on "AL" in the table on the other sheet

My table is set up on the other sheet as

| Name | AL# |
| --- | --- |
| [Persons name | FORMULA? |

I've tried Countifs(Sheet1!A:A,A1,Sheet1!
(where A1 is the persons name on sheet 2)

And I'm just stuck

Comment: Your data is on one row in the source sheet. However, you need a columnar layout to implement `COUNTIFS`. There are other alternatives which can be used in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is on one row in the source sheet. However, you need a columnar layout to implement `COUNTIFS`. There are other alternatives such as `SUMPRODUCT` which can be used in your case. See below demonstration.

> Sheet 1 : B2:J20 houses date wise leave data that contains "AL". Column A2:A20 holds unique names.

> Sheet 2: Cell A2 houses the name

Formula in such case would be:

`=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$B$2:$J$20="AL")*(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$20=Sheet2!A2))`